# La primera ejecución del Método render() de la librería requests_html me genera error

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Necesito renderizar el código fuente de una web para extraer datos, para esto la unica librería que he encontrado es requests_html, en su método render().

Este es el código:

```
 with HTMLSession() as s:     
    r=s.get(url, headers=headers)       
    r=s.post(url, data=login_data1, headers=headers)     
    r=s.get(url1, headers=headers) 
    # hasta aqui va bien     
    r=r.html.render()     
    print(r)
```

En la web de la librería advierten que en la primera ejecución se descargara automáticamente chromium  sin embargo cuando ejecuto mi código la descargas siempre se detiene entre el 13 y 30 % generando el siguiente error

```
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 447, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\http\client.py", line 491, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1052, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 911, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\Mineria34BOSS_EXITOSO_yaExtraeContratos_HaciendoloInteractivo_Requests_HTML.py", line 61, in <module>
    r=r.html.render()
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 586, in render
    self.browser = self.session.browser  # Automatically create a event loop and browser
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 730, in browser
    self._browser = self.loop.run_until_complete(super().browser)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 584, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests_html.py", line 714, in browser
    self._browser = await pyppeteer.launch(ignoreHTTPSErrors=not(self.verify), headless=True, args=self.__browser_args)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 305, in launch
    return await Launcher(options, **kwargs).launch()
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\launcher.py", line 119, in __init__
    download_chromium()
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\chromium_downloader.py", line 146, in download_chromium
    extract_zip(download_zip(get_url()), DOWNLOADS_FOLDER / REVISION)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\chromium_downloader.py", line 99, in download_zip
    for chunk in data.stream(10240):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\response.py", line 455, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError("Connection broken: %r" % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto', None, 10054, None)
```

Como puedo solucionar esto?.

Gracias de Antemano!.

Comment: En aplicaciones de este tipo es normal que la conexión se caiga. Pudiera ser esa la causa. Lo usual es poner el código en un try: except para recuperarse del error y reintentarlo nuevamente. Revisa y publica la parte pertinente de tu código.

Comment: Gracias por responder @CandidMoe te envio mi codigo  
```with HTMLSession() as s:
    r=s.get(url, headers=headers)  
    r=s.post(url, data=login_data1, headers=headers)
    r=s.get(url1, headers=headers) #hasta aqui va bien
    r=r.html.render()
    print (r)

```  
Estoy atento a tu respuesta. Nuevamente gracias de antemano.

Comment: @CandidMoe este proceso de descarga de Chromium requiere que la PC de ejecucion sea una computadora potente??

Comment: No lo creo. Si tu equipo puede hacer todo lo demás en forma normal (YouTube, torrents, etc.), también deberìa funcionar esto.

Comment: Ok @CandidMoe, entonces mi problema debe ser mi conexión a Internet?

Comment: No sé si el problema sea la conexión, pero es la primera cosa que revisaría. Como primera medida, usa un try-except para capturar el error específico.  Después usaria Wireshark para hacer una captura de paquetes y analizar lo enviado y recibido.

Comment: Ok, gracias!!, revisare esto y te estoy avisando.

Comment: @CandidMoe investigando mas al respecto me percate de que en pypi y en la pagina oficial de requests-html advierten de la necesidad de tener algunos paquetes linux para que pyppeteer trabaje, sabes sobre esto? podrías indicarme que paquetes son?, como los instalo?. Mi OS es Windows 10. Por favor ayudame con esto. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No se nada de Windows. Lo siento.

Comment: Okok, gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Saludos @CandidMoe, resolví mi problema usando el instalador que trae Python de pyppeteer, se llama pypeeteer-install, lo ejecute y el efectúo la instalación sin problemas del chromium, ya probé el ejemplo que aparece en la pagina de requests_HTML y esta completamente operativo.